# Document center in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

Our team is using an [intranet portal solution](https://www.mydock365.com/) for managing the documents of the team. Last day a few corrections were made in a document that was not to be done. Actually, I would like to know how can we find the person who changed the document. I checked it by visiting the library settings followed by versioning settings and then opened document version history. But I was not able to identify the person who did it as there were privacy settings.
It will be great if you can help me with finding the edited person.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view with the condition like modified greater than equal [today]  - 1 and display the column name, created, created by, modified, modified by - this will display the number documents which were modified in last two days.... it will give some ideas to locate the particular document.